# Registration function

Tags: php, mysql, database, registration

I built a registration feature for my project a few months ago, and it's been working perfectly until yesterday, and I'm not quite sure what's gone on, as I haven't changed anything with it for a good few weeks, at which time it was working last time I checked. I've attempted to debug it myself, but I can't find anything wrong with it, and I'm not sure what else to do!

The code is split across multiple pages, but essentially, here's what's going on:

**HTML Construction**

```
<?php require_once("clean.php"); ?>

<ul class="nav pull-right"><?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {?>
                            <li><a href="profile.php">Profile</a></li>
                            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li><?php
                        } else {?>
                            <li><a href="#register" class="account-register" data-toggle="modal" title="Register a new Screening account">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#login" class="account-login" data-toggle="modal" title="Login to your Screening profile">Login</a></li><?php
                        }?>
                    </ul>

<div id="register" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <?php require_once("register-controller.php"); ?>

        <!-- reCAPTCHA jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
             var RecaptchaOptions = {
                theme : 'white'
             };
         </script>

        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="registerLabel" class="modal-title">Register a new Screening account</h3>
        </div>

        <form name="register" action="" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal-body">

                <?php echo $register_bad_message; ?>
                <?php echo $register_good_message; ?>


                <input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
                <input class="input-block-level" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                <input class="input-block-level" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="file" class="profile-picture-upload" name="profile-image" alt="profile-image">
                <input class="input-block-level" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input class="input-block-level" type="password" name="confirm-password" class="span3" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                <?php include ("recaptcha_form.php") ?>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="Sign up!">Sign up!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Clean.php**

```
<?php
/*
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
*/
    function clean_string($string) {
        $string = trim($string);
        $string = utf8_decode($string);
        $string = str_replace("#", "&#35", $string); $string = str_replace("%", "&#37", $string);

        if (mysql_real_escape_string($string)) {
            $string = mysql_real_escape_string($string);
        }

        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $string = stripslashes($string);
        }

        return htmlentities($string);
    }
?>
```

**register-controller.php**

```
<?php
    /*
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
*/
    class SimpleImage {

       var $image;
       var $image_type;

       function load($filename) {

          $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
          $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
          if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

             $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
          } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

             $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
          }
       }
       function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

          if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
             imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
          } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

             imagepng($this->image,$filename);
          }
          if( $permissions != null) {

             chmod($filename,$permissions);
          }
       }
       function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

          if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
             imagejpeg($this->image);
          } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

             imagepng($this->image);
          }
       }
       function getWidth() {

          return imagesx($this->image);
       }
       function getHeight() {

          return imagesy($this->image);
       }
       function resizeToHeight($height) {

          $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
          $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
          $this->resize($width,$height);
       }

       function resizeToWidth($width) {
          $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
          $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
          $this->resize($width,$height);
       }

       function scale($scale) {
          $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
          $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
          $this->resize($width,$height);
       }

       function resize($width,$height) {
            $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
            if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF || $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
                $current_transparent = imagecolortransparent($this->image);
                if($current_transparent != -1) {
                    $transparent_color = imagecolorsforindex($this->image, $current_transparent);
                    $current_transparent = imagecolorallocate($new_image, $transparent_color['red'], $transparent_color['green'], $transparent_color['blue']);
                    imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $current_transparent);
                    imagecolortransparent($new_image, $current_transparent);
                } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
                    imagealphablending($new_image, false);
                    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
                    imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $color);
                    imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
                }
            }
            imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
            $this->image = $new_image;  
        }   

    }

    //Clean
    echo "before clean";
    $submit = clean_string($_POST['submit']);
    echo "after clean";

    if ($submit == 'Sign up!') {


        $first_name = clean_string($_POST['first-name']);
        $last_name = clean_string($_POST['last-name']);
        $email = clean_string($_POST['email']);
        $password = clean_string($_POST['password']);
        $confirm_password = clean_string($_POST['confirm-password']);

        //Output variables
        $register_bad_message = '';
        $register_good_message = '';

        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
        $privatekey = "6Ldbd8ASAAAAAFz8VT29H5w4WLNjsbI-mFY2QkaC";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
        if (!$resp->is_valid) {
            $errMessage = $resp->error;
            $register_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">The reCAPTCHA you entered wasn\'t correct. Please try again.</div>';?>
            <script>
                $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
            </script><?php
        } else {
            if ($first_name&&$last_name&&$email&&$password&&$confirm_password) {
                if ($password == $confirm_password) {
                    if (strlen($password) > 25 || strlen($password) < 6) {
                        $register_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Please enter a password between 6 and 25 characters.</div>';?>
                        <script>
                            $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
                        </script><?php
                    } else {
                        require_once("db_connect.php");
                        if($db_server) {
                            $first_name = clean_string($first_name);
                            $last_name = clean_string($last_name);
                            $email = clean_string($email);
                            $password = clean_string($password);
                            echo "1";
                            mysql_select_db($db_database);

                            $taken = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
                            $count = mysql_num_rows($taken);
                            if ($count > 0) {
                                $register_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">The email you have entered is already associated with a Screening account. Please choose another.</div>';?>
                                <script>
                                    $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
                                </script><?php
                            } else {
                                if ($_FILES) {
                                    //Put file properties into variables
                                    $file_name = $_FILES['profile-image']['name'];
                                    $file_size = $_FILES['profile-image']['size'];
                                    $file_tmp_name = $_FILES['profile-image']['tmp_name'];


                                    //Determine filetype
                                    switch ($_FILES['profile-image']['type']) {
                                        case 'image/jpeg': $ext = "jpg"; break;
                                        case 'image/png': $ext = "png"; break;
                                        default: $ext = ''; break;
                                    }

                                    if ($ext) {
                                        //Check filesize
                                        if ($file_size < 5242880) {
                                            //Process file - resize, clean up filename and move to safe location
                                            $image = new SimpleImage();
                                            $image->load($file_tmp_name);
                                            $image->resizeToWidth(250);
                                            $image->save($file_tmp_name);


                                            $n = "$file_name";
                                            $n = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", "", $n);
                                            $n = strtolower($n);
                                            $n = "avatars/$n";
                                            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $n);
                                        } else {
                                            $register_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Please ensure your chosen file is less than 5MB.</div>';?>
                                            <script>
                                                $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
                                            </script><?php
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        $register_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Please ensure your image is of filetype .jpg or.png.</div>';?>
                                        <script>
                                            $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
                                        </script><?php
                                    }
                                }
                                $password = md5($password);
                                $query = "INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, email, password, image) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password', '$n')";
                                mysql_query($query) or die("Insert failed. " . mysql_error() . "<br />" . $query);
                                $register_good_message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Registration successful!
                                                            <br />
                                                            <a href='#login' data-toggle='modal' title='Login to your Screening profile'>Login now</a></div>';?>
                                <script>
                                    $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
                                </script><?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            $register_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Error: could not connect to the database.</div>';?>
                            <script>
                                $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
                            </script><?php
                        }
                        require_once("db_close.php");
                    }
                } else {
                    $register_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Passwords failed to match. Please try again.</div>';?>
                    <script>
                        $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
                    </script><?php
                }
            } else {
                $register_bad_message = '<div class="alert alert-error">Please fill in all fields before continuing.</div>';?>
                <script>
                    $('a.account-register').trigger('click');
                </script><?php
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

If I turn error reporting on, the message I get is:

before clean Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 after clean Notice: Undefined index: first-name in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\register-controller.php on line 100 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Notice: Undefined index: last-name in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\register-controller.php on line 101 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in \ICS-FILESHARE\WWW\newmedia.leeds.ac.uk\ug10\cs10aer\screening_new\clean.php on line 11

But I've checked my database connections and everything seems OK - other features on the website, such as logging in and adding, deleting and amending database details are all working perfectly, and they use the same database connection script, so it's just this registration feature which has suddenly broken, for reasons I can't understand.

Comment: try RE-installing mysql, or the php version you are using, because this seems a whole lot of headache to debug

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working on my university's server and have no access to any facility like this. All I can really do is code, and see errors using error reporting.

Comment: +1 for cleaning strings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to connect to the database before calling `mysql_real_escape_string`. When the code reaches this point the connection has not yet been made:

```
//Clean
echo "before clean";
$submit = clean_string($_POST['submit']);
echo "after clean";
```

Alternatively you can use the not-as-safe `mysql_escape_string` function. `mysql_real_escape_string` needs a database connection because it needs knowledge of the connection's characters encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So in, my original register-controller, where would the best place be to connect to the database, to ensure all my strings were still cleaned effectively and secure? I don't want to just stick in db_connect anywhere without my app being secure, regardless of whether it worked or not. I've already got a db_connect.php in there, so can I connect twice, with only one db_close.php, or would I have to reshuffle the one I've already got?

Apologies for my lack of knowledge, I'm still quite new to PHP.

Comment: It seems $submit is used only to compare with a literal string. That's safe without sanitation. You can remove the call to clean_string.

Answer (score 1):

Better still, don't use the php mysql functions and the soon to be deprecated mysql_real_esape_string() but instead use the newer and more secure PDO.